# ¿Cómo saber cuánto pesa en bytes un List<Object> en C# para evitar pasarme de un tamaño específico al responder un servicio WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

Ncesito saber cuanto va pensando un List en C# dado que estoy haciendo un servicio `WCF` y este me pone un problema al pasar grandes cantidades de datos en el `Result` del servicio.

El servicio se encarga de hacer una consulta a la Base de Datos y retonar los datos consultados, cuando no son muchos, no hya problema, pero cuando son todos los campos de una tabla (250 mil o a veces hasta más) pues el servicio nunca contesta y dice que hay error de memoria, he utilizado el probador por defecto que despliega Visual Studio y lo configuro a 2147483647 bytes

```
 maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
```

Pero aún así hay error, de igual manera he utilizado SOAP UI para ver si podría ser problema de esto y no, ahí me lanza un error al recibir respuesta.

Según veo, es problema con el tamaño de los datos que se responden, y no he encontrado la forma de evitar ese bloqueo por lo que pensé que podría controlarlo verificando que esa lista que retorno no supere esa cantidad de bytes (no sé si ese especificamente sea el problema, solo busco soluciones), y si lo va a superar, no agregarle más datos para que el servicio pueda responder y no lance un error nada más.

Muchas gracias a todos de antemano.

Comment: realmente necestas que te devuelva todos los datos? , puedes agregarle a tu respuesta una paginacion, es decir supon que el servicio max te devuelve 1000 renglones y ademas en otro parametro que el total son 28000, en tu siguiente llamada le dices que ahora quieres la pagnia 2, y te devuelve los registros de 1001 a 2000 y asi.  Como puedes ver eso implica modificar tu sp para la paginacion, y a tu metodo para los parametros extra entrada y salida.

Comment: Si debes pasar tal cantidad de información, quizás podrías plantearte pasar los datos por streaming (https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/large-data-and-streaming) asíncronamente. Podrías hacer un .zip en memoria con la librería IonicZip, pasarlo por streaming, descomprimirlo una vez recibido y manejar la información.

Comment: Deseas pasar 2147 megas de información? estamos hablando de 2 gb. en registros.